# vi - getting an error E212: Can't open file for writing

Tags: unix, vim, osx-lion

I am following this tutorial for setting opendiff for git: http://thomashunter.name/blog/set-opendiff-filemerge-as-your-git-diff-tool-on-os-x/

I open vi like it said in tutorial, write some lines and try :wq but get error - error E212: Can't open file for writing

I browsed stack overflow for a little bit, and tried typing

```
sudo vim ~/bin/git-diff.sh
```

But I am also getting the same error.

I haven't had much experience with unix based systems, so what am i to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a `bin` directory below `~` (which is `/Users/username`). The error message of `"~/bin/git-diff.sh" [New DIRECTORY]` at the bottom of the vim screen should have been a hint

Comment: [New DIRECTORY] hehe i saew this, but as first time vim user, it really hinted me nothing ;-)