# Can't open file for writing when vim recover file with swp file

Tags: file, vim, editor, backup, temporary-files

I want to recover the `/home/lufei/market/resources/views/user.blade.php`, here is the place of `swp` file.

```
> lufei@localhost:~/market$ ls resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp 
> resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp
```

I use `vim -r resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp` to recover the file, I get this,

> E306: Cannot open resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp Press ENTER or
>   type command to continue

When I use `sudo vim -r resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp` I can open the file, but when I use `:wq` in the vim I get

> "/root/market/resources/views/user.blade.php"
>   "/root/market/resources/views/user.blade.php" E212: Can't open file
>   for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue

From the info above I think vim want to save the file to the root directory. From the [vi - getting an error E212: Can't open file for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15898593/6521116), I guess if I create path `/root/market/resources/views/` may work. But I want to directly save the file to the right place `/home/lufei/market/resources/views/user.blade.php`. So I use `su && cd /home/lufei/market` then `vim -r resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp`. But when I `:wq` in vim , I also get

```
"~/market/resources/views/user.blade.php"                                                        
"~/market/resources/views/user.blade.php" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

From above trying, no matter I use normal user or the root user, when I recover the file, vim  will try to save the file to the wrong place which path is not exist.

**Can I directly recover the file to the right place**, without create a temp path and then copy the recoveried file back to the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by the edit session crush like the items 2 in command `sudo vim market/resources/views/user.blade.php`. It make the swp file make the wong original file path.    Note I really not have the `/root/market/resources/views/user.blade.php` file even the `/root/market/` path. This is the first I create the file `user.blade.php` and without save it, and then shutdown the computer.

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Thu Nov  9 17:33:23 2017
         file name: ~root/market/resources/views/user.blade.php
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: localhost
        process ID: 128985
While opening file "resources/views/user.blade.php"

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r resources/views/user.blade.php"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

Solution:

- 1. `sudo vim market/resources/views/user.blade.php`, if vim show above info, just press R and then save the file. If it not show above info, use `:rec(over)`, then save the file.
- 2. use vim open any file env create a new file, with `sudo vim aaa.txt`, then use `:rec(over) user.blade.php` then save it. This will save the file to user.blade.php not the aaa.txt. Make sure the aaa.txt and .user.blade.php in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enough access rights to open the file as `lufei`, and then start your recovery:

```
$ chmod u=rw resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp
$ vim -r resources/views/.user.blade.php.swp
```

Comment: I've tried with sudo, even the root user. While nothing works.